# access logs in cron jobs kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm running a *CronJob* in *kubernetes*, the jobs complete successfully and I log output to the log file inside `(path: storage/logs)` but I cannot access that file due to the container being in a completed state.

Here is my job *yaml*:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
  kind: CronJob
  metadata:
    labels:
      chart: cronjobs-0.1.0
    name: cron-cronjob1
    namespace: default
  spec:
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    jobTemplate:      
      spec:
        template:
          metadata:          
            labels:
              app: cron
              cron: cronjob1
          spec:
            containers:
            - args:
              - /usr/local/bin/php
              - -c
              - /var/www/html/artisan bulk:import
              env:
              - name: DB_CONNECTION
                value: postgres
              - name: DB_HOST
                value: postgres
              - name: DB_PORT
                value: "5432"
              - name: DB_DATABASE
                value: xxx
              - name: DB_USERNAME
                value: xxx
              - name: DB_PASSWORD
                value: xxxx
              - name: APP_KEY
                value: xxxxx
              image: registry.xxxxx.com/xxxx:2ecb785-e927977
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              name: cronjob1
              ports:
              - containerPort: 80
                name: http
                protocol: TCP              
            imagePullSecrets:
            - name: xxxxx
            restartPolicy: OnFailure          
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
    schedule: '* * * * *'
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
```

Is there anyway I can get my log file content displayed with `kubectl log <podname>` command or other alternatives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I guess you know that the pod is kept around as you have `successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3`. Presumably your point is that your logging is going logged to a file and not stdout and so you don't see it with `kubectl logs`. If so maybe you could also log to stdout or put something into the job to log the content of the file at the end, [for example](https://blog.powerupcloud.com/kubernetes-pod-management-using-fluentd-as-a-sidecar-container-and-prestop-lifecycle-hook-part-iv-428b5f4f7fc7) in a [PreStop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/).

Comment: brilliant, im gonna use log management cause there are few log files that i want to access centralized

Answer (score 19):

`Cronjob` runs pod according to the `spec.schedule`. After completing the task the pod's status will be set as `completed`, but the `cronjob` controller doesn't delete the pod after completing. And the log file content still there in the pod's container filesystem. So you need to do:

```sh
# here  you can get the pod_name from the stdout of the cmd `kubectl get pods`
$ kubectl logs -f -n default <pod_name>
```

Comment: this works only standard outputs, im logging into file inside the pod i need different mechanism

Comment: I've noticed that as well, this only works on stdout, does not work on stderr.

Comment: @linehrr I did not check that, maybe you are right.